# Google-maps:Triggering event in infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

Trying to trigger an event in the infowindow..i have the following content string

```
var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
           '<div id="siteNotice">'+
           '</div>'+
           '<h2 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">'+data.name+'</h2>'+
           '<div id="bodyContent">'+
           '<p>'+data.address+'</p>'+
           '<p></p>'+
           '<p>Do You Want to change search location</p>'+
           '<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="alert(\"infoWindow\")">'+
           '</div>'+
           '</div>';
```

here the alert statement is no triggering..Actually i need to implement a event that whenever i click the button i need to store that particular coordinates into local storage
any suggestions would be  appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Change `'<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="alert(\"infoWindow\")">'+`

To `'<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="saveData()">'+`

saveData() Function used `latlng` from marker which should be set GLOBAL (At start of script)

```
function saveData() {
  var latlng = marker.getPosition();
  var lat=latlng.lat();
  var lng=latlng.lng();
//store data
 }
```

**EDIT** 
Changed from(cut & paste error in origonal)

```
var lat=" + latlng.lat();
var lng=" + latlng.lng();
```

Comment: hi getting error Cannot call method 'getPosition' of undefined

Comment: getPosition is a method of the marker class see `https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker`. As I had no means of knowing what your marker is called I used 'marker'

Comment: hi it says unexpected toke here:   var lat=" + latlng.lat();..anything wrong wth the line?

Comment: See edit to answer. See `https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlinfo_v3 ` for additional information

Comment: Is marker GLOBAL? ie `var marker; ` just after `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: i have a separate js file..what i am trying to do is..i save some favourite places and place markers ..in the infowindow of marker ill give a button..when i click the button i need to store that coordinates... and i am implementing search for hotels or some places from that coordinates ...here is my js file code..   http://pastebin.com/74ULam9h

Comment: I am lost with your code. OOjavascript is not for me I think it has to use to many 'tricks' to accomplish. I suggest you pass the parameters separately to saveData() and see if this works.